# how to transfer data received from user to json

Tags: php, json, class, oop, append

I have a class that implements receiving data from the user,
there is a getInput method in this class

im use

```
$readData = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$data = fgets($readData);
```

and `return $data;`

and I have another class that calls the previous, there are 2 methods in it

```
getIinput()
run()
```

in the end, I have 2 variables received from the user and the run method to output them, but how do I add these 2 variables into a json file?

to come out

```
{
    "firstname": "(data from first var)"
    "lastname": "(data from second var)"
}
```

json file appears here as db and should be overwritten after the next call

Comment: `echo json_encode(['firstname' => getIinput(), 'lastname' => run()]);`?

Comment: @u_mulder methods do not do this. how will the code understand how to write it?

Comment: @annkarsksya `json_encode()` is a language defined method, just like if you were using `mysql_*()` methods, so the code will understand it

Comment: Methods do not do __what__?

Comment: @u_mulder Forget it, you suggest immediately translating everything into json, but I still need to write it to a file

Comment: So replace `echo` with `file_put_contents` for example.

Comment: @u_mulder can this be implemented as a separate class?

Comment: It can be implemented any way you want.